# how could i use webform (.aspx) file in MVC 5 Views using visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i have created Asp.net mvc 5 project by learning mvc 5 tutorial, but my question is that how could i use .aspx file in view in mvc 5 web application using visual studio 2013

Comment: You can't use a web form in an MVC view, you can however just add an aspx page to the project and it will work just fine.

Comment: i have  already added it, but my question is that how to integrate controller to that particular webform in MVC?

Comment: You can't mix and match Views/Controllers and web forms code.

Comment: @SavanTripathi - out of interest, is there a specific interest why you want to use the aspx view engine rather than the newer (and subjectively better...) [razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor)?

Comment: yes i agree it is out of intrest but my problem is that i want to use the controls which asp.net toolbox provide. is there any way to use control in .cshtml (razor view) but it is very tough for me to deal with

Comment: Nope. ASP.NET webforms controls are not usable in an ASP.NET MVC views.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the markup in your ASPX view is correct related to MVC standards e.g

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MVC.Master" `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.ImportantModel>" %>`
```